# Number setting for bullets

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint

I'm currently building a PowerPoint Plugin that creates a .xml file with the text format information. 
One task of it is to save the bullet settings for character ranges, as I'm splitting the text manually. I'm struggling at the reassembly of the bullets:  
How can I set the numbers of my bullet points (per code)? When I try to do

```
<TextRange>.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Number = X
```

I get the Error "ReadOnly attribute".  
Also is there a better way than splitting my text manually? I divide it by checking for differences in Font.size, style, color, name, etc. `<TextRange>.Paragraphs(i)` returns a lot of empty paragraphs..  
Thanks!

***Edit**
An example would be

1. Thats

   1. A
   2. test

I would have 3 TextRanges (Thats, A, test) and would like to create the same bullets as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, using the current selected shape as an example:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
        ' is it an empty paragraph?
        If Len(.Paragraphs(x).Text) > 0 Then
            .Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style = ppBulletArabicPeriod
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve another "error". I already had tested that command but it didnt work for me. I used it in a rather long algorithm - which disabled screen updating. And I used breakpoints after the command..